# Error on Credentials handshake of Public Test Environement

Tags: shareandcharge

I am seeing the following error on step 3 Credentials handshake of OCN Node registration. (https://shareandcharge.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OCN/pages/265945122/OCN+Node+registration#3.-Credentials-handshake)

When I send the credentials handshake, I see the following error:

```
{
  "status_code": 3001,
  "status_message": "Failed to request from https://edrv-ocpi-dev.herokuapp.com/ocpi/versions: Cannot deserialize instance of `snc.openchargingnetwork.node.models.ocpi.OcpiResponse<java.util.List<snc.openchargingnetwork.node.models.ocpi.Version>>` out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: (String)\"[{\"status_code\":1000,\"data\":{\"versions\":[{\"version\":\"2.2\",\"url\":\"https://edrv-ocpi-dev.herokuapp.com/ocpi/2.2\"}]},\"timestamp\":\"2020-02-15T07:48:58.364Z\"}]\"; line: 1, column: 1]",
  "timestamp": "2020-02-15T07:48:58.390914Z"
}
```

This is the request I am sending:

```
curl -X POST \
 https://qa-client.emobilify.com/ocpi/2.2/credentials \
 -H 'Accept: */*' \
 -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
 -H 'Authorization: Token 21c158fc-****-****-****-************' \
 -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
 -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
 -H 'Content-Length: 297' \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -H 'Host: qa-client.emobilify.com' \
 -H 'Postman-Token: 8cb3bcba-2cc0-4923-9290-04be261fb686,fe8e2916-ee94-4676-a60a-ad64e3869dcc' \
 -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0' \
 -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
 -d '{
  "token": "9e9cf68b-****-****-****-dcb7fcaa341e",
  "url": "https://edrv-ocpi-dev.herokuapp.com/ocpi/versions",
  "roles": [{
   "party_id": "EDV",
   "country_code": "NL",
   "role": "EMSP",
   "business_details": {
    "name": "eDRV Technologies B.V."
   }
  }]
 }'
```

I have setup a quick server on heroku as per step 2 in the tutorial. Here is what the versions endpoint code looks like:

```
app.get("/ocpi/versions", authorize, async (_, res) => {
    res.send([{
        status_code: 1000,
        data: {
            versions: [{
                version: "2.2",
                url: `${PUBLIC_URL}/ocpi/2.2`
            }]
        },
        timestamp: new Date()
    }])
})
```

Is there something I am missing in the request?

Answer (score 2):

The original version of OCPI 2.2 contains an error. The bugfix branch contains the correct type: https://github.com/ocpi/ocpi/blob/release-2.2-bugfixes/version_information_endpoint.asciidoc

You can change your response to the following to make it work:

```
res.send({
    status_code: 1000,
    data: [{
        version: "2.2",
        url: `${PUBLIC_URL}/ocpi/2.2`
    }],
    timestamp: new Date()
})
```

Comment: Wait, so there isn't a "versions" list, but instead an unnamed list of versions?  I guess they are using the "data" label as the name of the array?

The PDF I'm looking at still shows the "versions" label but the example (where it strips out the "data" part) shows only the []'s to make the array.  That needs to be better clarified.

Comment: @AlanStewart yes, in the OCPI v2.2 document you likely have there is a mistake. The data type expected in this instance is an array, rather than a map with a sole property (that being `versions` - the array). This has since been fixed, but is not yet reflected in the 2.2 documentation proper.

Comment: Thank you.  That's good to know.  I understand that documents are very hard to keep up-to-date but I'm pleased to know this will be fixed.  I've noticed other very minor little oopsies here and there.  Hopefully those will get fixed in due time as well.